# In MongoDB, how to calculate an average ($avg) per class ($group) after joining several collections ($lookup)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here I have two collections :

conso

```
{   
  "_id" : ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c322fd"),
  "client" : "1",
  "conso" : "4"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1f31cf906003"),
  "client" : "1",
  "conso" : "2"
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906004"),
  "client" : "2",
  "conso" : "10"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2890"),
  "client" : "2",
  "conso" : "20"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59301c39029afaf4450e2885"),
  "client" : "3",
  "conso" : "18"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59301c39030afaf4450e2885"),
  "client" : "3",
  "conso" : "12"
}
```

class

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f6d219d345f0066299c1fd6"),
   "CLIENT" : "1",
   "class" : "A"
}    
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e6d219c345f0066299c1fd6"),
   "CLIENT" : "2",
   "class" : "A"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e6d02c97d9426227fa00401"),
   "CLIENT" : "3",
   "class" : "B"
}
```

I would like to have :

```
{"class" : "A", avg : 9}

{"class" : "B", avg : 15}
```

My code :

```
db.conso.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id : {class: "$class"}, avg: { $avg: "$conso" }}},
    {$lookup: {from: "class", localField: "client", foreignField: "CLIENT", as: "class_info"}}
    ]);
```

and I obtain :

```
{ "_id" : { "class" : null }, "avg" : 11, "class_info" : [ ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having the below changes to your `conso` collection and your query, we can get the desired result.

> Modification in `conso` collection

The attribute conso in the conso collection takes a string value which we need to change it into number, so the modified collection will look like

```
{"_id":"5684f3c454b1fd6926c322fd","client":"1","conso":4},
{"_id":"56d82612b63f1f31cf906003","client":"1","conso":2},
{"_id":"56d82612b63f1c31cf906004","client":"2","conso":10},
{"_id":"59301c39028afaf3450e2890","client":"2","conso":20},
{"_id":"59301c39029afaf4450e2885","client":"3","conso":18},
{"_id":"59301c39030afaf4450e2885","client":"3","conso":12}
```

If you are not willing to modify your collection then you can use [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) to convert the conso string into number, this step will add another pipeline stage( [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) ) to our existing query between $lookup and $group. Please note that [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) will be giving error if the value cannot be converted to int.

> Modification to the query

Do the `$lookup` first and then perform `$group` and in the group stage _id part need to changed from `class: "$class"` to `class: "$class_info.class"`

Modified query will be

```
db.conso.aggregate([
    { $lookup: { 
       from: "class",
       localField: "client", 
       foreignField: "CLIENT", 
       as: "class_info"}
    }, 
    { $group: {_id : {class: "$class_info.class"}, avg: { $avg: "$conso" }}},
]);
```

Hope it Helps!